# add Dynamic Columns in addition to Static columns

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a dataTable with some columns, which are not supposed to change.

```
            <p:dataTable id="datatable" value="#{phase.tasks}" var="task">
             <p:commandButton id="Testcycles"
                                            action="#{testprojectProducer.doAddTestCycle(phase)}"
                                            update=":formID:Tasks" title="add Test "
                                            icon="ui-icon-plus fa fa-plus">
                                            <!--                                                   <p:ajax oncomplete="#{testprojectProducer.doAddTest(phase)}" update=":formID:Tasks"></p:ajax> -->
                                        </p:commandButton>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:panelGrid>
                                    <h:panelGroup columns="2"
                                        style="display:block; text-align:right">                            
                                <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                        Task    
                                        </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{task.name}" id="description"
                                    title="#{task.description}" />
                                <pe:tooltip for="description" value="#{task.description}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                        Tool    
                                        </f:facet>
                                <p:commandLink value="#{task.tool}" ajax="false"
                                    action="#{fileLinkController.openFile()}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                        Result  
                                        </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{task.resultDocuments}" />
                            </p:column>
```

In addition to that, the user should have the possibility, to add new columns.

```
        <p:columns value="#{task.listTest}"
                    var="sometest">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Test
                </f:facet>
                    <p:inputText id="comment"
                        value="#{sometest.description}">
                    </p:inputText>
        </p:columns> 
    </p:dataTable>
```

Here is the method where I add my new Tests.

```
    public void doAddTest(Phase phase) {
      for (Task task : phase.getTasks()) {

        task.getListTest().add(new Test(task));

    }


}
```

I'm aware of the fact that it is not possible to control the columns on a per-row basis, but I really need some advice, how I can keep my static columns and add the dynamic ones.

doAddTest() is invoked with a button, you can find under the  Tag. 
It is first of all important that the extra columns are displayed in the table and the user has the option to leave a comment. with this method, the content of the columns will be written into the database.

```
    public String doSave() {

    if (testprojectProducer.isAddMode()) {
        testprojectAddEvent.fire(testprojectProducer.getTestproject());

        }
    } else {
        testprojectUpdateEvent.fire(testprojectProducer.getTestproject());
    }

    return Pages.LIST_TESTPROJECT;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? It should just work if you add both static `<p:column>` tags and a `<p:columns>` tag in the same datatable

Comment: your code is missing some important parts , where your function doAddTest will be invoked ? , the part of   finding the data-table component and update its child's with the new created column .please post all of your code . if you don't know that let know to help

Comment: Thank you, you are very helpful.@Ahmed Gamal unfortunately, I don't have Access to my Code until April27th. But I will get back to you with that. @Kuktltje IT works fine with other lists I tested it. But Not with listTests and that is the problem.

Comment: I updated my code.